# Remove eventListener in object oriented JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am new to OOP in JavaScript!!!

I am trying to remove a eventlistener but can not make it work:

```
window.addEventListener('resize', this.adapt.eventBind(this), true);
window.removeEventListener('resize', this.adapt.eventBind(this), true);
```

This is the function that bind the eventlistener:

```
Function.prototype.eventBind = function(parentObj) {
var func = this;
var args = new Array();
for(var i = 0; i < arguments.length - 1; i++) {
    args[i] = arguments[i+1];
}
var temp = function(evt) {
    if(typeof(evt) != "undefined") {
        if(typeof(evt["target"]) != "undefined") args[0] = evt["target"];
        else args[0] = evt["srcElement"];
    }
    return func.apply(parentObj, args);
}
return(temp);
}
```

Kind regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function you pass into `removeEventListener` has to be the *same* function you gave `addEventListener`; but in your case, you're creating a new, different function.

So you'll have to remember it, perhaps on that same object:

```
this.resizeListener = this.adapt.eventBind(this);
window.addEventListener('resize', this.resizeListener, true);
window.removeEventListener('resize', this.resizeListener, true);
```

(Note that even though I use `this.resizeListener` when adding/removing, it doesn't have the `this` problem code looking like that would normally have, because I've already bound it using your `eventBind`.)

Comment: You cannot remove event listeners for anonymous functions listeners right ?

Comment: @GoodSp33d: The *functions* may be anonymous, but you have to have a reference to them to remove them. So `var f = function() { ... };` gives us an anonymous function, which we have a reference to in the `f` variable, so if we added that we could remove it (using `f`). But if we don't have a reference to the function (`addEventListener(function() { ... });` then I don't know of a way to remove it.

Comment: @GoodSp33d Good question. Made me understand the explanation even better.