# Can't remove eventlisteners TypeScript/OOP JavaScript

Tags: javascript, oop, drag-and-drop, typescript

The onMouseUp is fired, but it doesn't remove the `EventListeners`. I've read a lot of post where people are having trouble, and it's because they don't remove the same function as they add, and reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24647117/remove-eventlistener-in-object-oriented-javascript) I'm thinking that I might have the same problem, but how do I deal with it? I don't fully understand the answer on the linked question.

```
class DragAndDrop {
    item: Item;
    documentBody: HTMLBodyElement;
    constructor(documentBody: HTMLBodyElement, item: Item) {
        this.documentBody = documentBody;
        this.item = item;
        this.documentBody.addEventListener("mousedown", this.onmousedown.bind(this));
    }
    onmousedown(event: MouseEvent): void {
        if (CollisionDetector.pointInRect(event.clientX, event.clientY, this.item)) {
            this.documentBody.addEventListener("mousemove", this.onMouseMove.bind(this));
            this.documentBody.addEventListener("mouseup", this.onMouseUp.bind(this));
        }
    }
    onMouseMove(event: MouseEvent): void {
        this.item.x = event.clientX;
        this.item.y = event.clientY;
    }
    onMouseUp(event: MouseEvent): void {
        this.documentBody.removeEventListener("mousemove", this.onMouseMove.bind(this));
        this.documentBody.removeEventListener("mouseup", this.onMouseUp.bind(this));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code you use `.bind`.

## Issues

- `.bind` **creates a copy of the function**.

i.e. `foo.bind !== foo`

- `bind` is not type safe : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/tips/bind.html

## Solution

Use an arrow function. I do it for `mousedown` for you:

```
class DragAndDrop {
    item: Item;
    documentBody: HTMLBodyElement;
    constructor(documentBody: HTMLBodyElement, item: Item) {
        this.documentBody = documentBody;
        this.item = item;
        this.documentBody.addEventListener("mousedown", this.onmousedown);
    }
    onmousedown = (event: MouseEvent): void => {
        if (CollisionDetector.pointInRect(event.clientX, event.clientY, this.item)) {
            // Similarly ...
        }
    }
}
```

## More

More on arrow functions : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/arrow-functions.html